# Select class that has the same URL id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a filter on one page. When the user enters this page, if they have an ID I want this filter to trigger that ID.

For example, if the id = event, I want the event filter to trigger.

Is there a more fluid way to display this, rather then showing each individual id?

For example, this is working below:-

```
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#events') > -1 ) {
        $(".btn.events").trigger('click'); 
    }
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#video') > -1 ) {
        $(".btn.video").trigger('click'); 
    }
```

But it would work much better if this was fluid. I really need to say if the URL has an ID, then find the button with the same class and the trigger this event.

Thank you

Comment: Show your URL format?

Comment: please share your url format

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the class on the target element(s) always matches the content of the URL fragment then you can genericise this quite simply:

```
var fragment = window.location.hash;
if (fragment) {
  var target = fragment.substring(1);
  $(".btn." + target).trigger('click'); 
}
```

Comment: Or in plain JavaScript - as I know Rory already knows - `document.querySelector(\`.btn.${target}\`).click()`, though bear in mind that a programmatic click event may not trigger the desired event (depending on what that event is, and whether or not the browser requires a genuine user-interaction).

Comment: Hi Rory, brilliant thank you! One little question, the click function doesn't fire as the following generates:- URL/#events/ however, simply removing the last / works, so:- 'URL/#events' Can this be edited via the above too?

Comment: Sure, in that case you need to remove the slashes from the fragment: `fragment.substring(1).replace(/\//g, '');`

Comment: Thats brilliant, exactly what I needed. Thanks Rory!

Answer (score 1):

Set an array of possible/allowed hashes, then compose dynamically the selector

```
var myhash =  ['#events', '#video', ... ];
var hash = location.hash;

if (myhash.includes(hash)) {
   var el = $(".btn." + hash.substring(1));
   if (el.length) {
       el.trigger('click'); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the exact URL pattern. This code snippet will work assuming you have query parameters.

```
const currentUrl = new URL(location.href);
const queryParams = currentUrl.search;
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryParams);
const searchId = (searchParams && searchParams.has("id") && searchParams.get("id")) || "";
if(searchId) {
  const ele = [".btn", searchId].join(".");
  $(ele).trigger('click'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest:

1. Get ID from Url using: window.location.search and save the value of Id in new parameter value_id.
2. After that you can create general function if value_id is not empty:

   $(".btn." + value_id).trigger('click');